# how to use awscli on an s3 bucket in mumbai region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, s3-bucket

I am trying to do

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name  --region ap-south-1
```

But it keeps giving me the following error

> A client error (PermanentRedirect) occurred when calling the
>   ListObjects operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be
>   addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future
>   requests to this endpoint.

The same command runs perfectly fine for buckets in other regions, but not for buckets in Mumbai (ap-south-1) region

Help!!

Answer (score 1):

So i updates the awscli to the latest version

```
$sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli
$aws --version
$aws-cli/1.11.109 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-48-generic botocore/1.5.72
```

It works now!